# Are the any alternatives to Pandas Merge that work with medium datasets?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV datasets with 57 MB (387427L, 22C) and 32 MB(569400L, 9C) and I've loaded them to Pandas Dataframes.

```
p = pd.read_csv('Dataset/p_data.csv')
w = pd.read_csv('Dataset/w_data.csv')
```

When I tried to do a MERGE I've got a "Memory Error". My computer has an Intel i5 and 8GB Memory and I am using Conda with Python 3.6.

```
g = p.merge(w, on=['X_ID'])
```

I've looked for several solutions, like using Dask and a Workaround with Sqlite, but they give me the same problem. Arrow doesn't have a MERGE feature.

Could someone give me a help?

Comment: Please share the command/s you have tried

Comment: Make sure that your dataframes have correct `dtypes` in them. If you have number values in there and you know in advance their range use dtypes with smaller memory usage like `dtype('uint8')`

Comment: Can you post the code too?

Comment: Thank. I've just edited

Comment: Some ideas. Set the index of each df to 'X_ON' before merging. And check the memory use of each dataframe with the `df.info(memory_use='deep')` command. Post the `df.info()` here.

Comment: @576i using index gave me also an error. p memory usage: 168.4 MB, w memory usage: 69.7 MB

Comment: You can set the index on csv import as part of the read_csv command, maybe that works for you. Also, check if your python and pandas installation are current, because a 164MB file is not that big.

Comment: @hellpanderr Thanks. I've tried to "squeeze" the most I could. Same error

Comment: Do you use 64-bit version of python?

Comment: @hellpanderr Yes

Comment: After some type conversion p memory usage: 33.2 MB, w memory usage: 18.6 MB . There should be something else

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
g = p.merge(w, on=['X_ID'], how = 'outer')
```

It worked for me.